# RegEx Lookbehind / Lookahead in Google Data Studio

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I need to use RegEx in Google Data Studio.

As part of a project I need to make a dashboard in Google Data Studio, but I'm having trouble extracting different elements from the column:

```
P. (number) - Title/\\/Author/\\/Topic
```

***Examples***:

> P. 9 - Harry Pottér sold: 2.2m in 2019/\/John Johnson/\/Movies
>
> P. 120 - The Readers Say, that/\/NA/\/Debat

I need to extract `Title`, `Author` and `Topic` into separate columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way it could be achieved using 3 [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487) fields:

> 1. **Title**
>
> ```
> REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field, "^P\\. \\d+ - (.*)/./.*/./.*$")
> ```
>
> 2. **Author**
>
> ```
> REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field, "/./(.*)/./\\w+$")
> ```
>
> 3. **Topic**
>
> ```
> REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field, "(\\w+)$")
> ```

Created a [Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/4fbdc14f-a9dc-4f4e-9322-58adf65157b5) (Google Sheets Embedded) to demonstrate.

[image: 3]]